# What do we share?

Tags: riddle

We are a town in Lincolnshire and a funeral carriage; a mechanism for filling water tanks and a book of photographs; and, according to hearsay, a strong form of uniform continuity and a semi-precious stone.

What do we share?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You share a fear of censorship. All the clues point to things that contain  insults/curses. The ones that are "hearsay" contain curses that are heard, not spelled.

A town in Lincolnshire:

> [S**cunt**horpe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe)

Funeral carriage:

> He**arse**

Mechanism for filling water tanks:

> [Ballcock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballcock) -> **ball**? **cock**? Both seem right

Book of photographs:

> S**crap**book (or al**bum** as OP's comment)

Strong form of uniform continuity:

> [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) -> **shits**

Semi-precious stone:

> [Jasper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasper) -> **ass**

There may be another stone that contains a "bad" word, but that was the first I came across on the listing I found. **Edit by Rand al'Thor on advice of OP:**

> Lapis lazuli -> **piss**

Comment: This one didn't last long! You're almost there. The mechanism for filling water tanks didn't have a "hearsay" qualifier, so "hose" is wrong. "Scrapbook" I will allow, although I was thinking of "album". "Cassiterite" I won't. "Ass" is correct spelling in some parts of the world and does not fit with the "hearsay" requirement. So, well done and two to go! :)

Comment: @h34 Ah, the hearsay thing threw me, but that makes sense. How about *ballcock* and *jasper*? ;)

Comment: "Ballcock" is correct - with the second morpheme intended as the relevant one. As for "jasper", it's not what I intended, but I was going to give it to you. But given that "ass" and "arse" (from "hearse") are forms of the same word, it would make two of the six words the same, so for elegance there's still this one to go! :)

Comment: I must have missed the unique words requirement. If you want specific words only, try to make the clues specific enough that they only point to one word each.